# Laravel Blade, Pass a function through @include without checking if it exists in main view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am learning Laravel (and php) and creating views in blade.  Because I'll have a number of very similar views, I want to keep as much of the formatting in reusable files that I pass a few variables to to customize for each file. This is working well for most instances, but fails when I need to pass a function to the included view.

**show.blade**

```
  @include('_twocol_row_content',
  [
    'field' => 'Content',
    'value' => $entry->blocks,
    'interface' => blockDisplay()
  ])
```

**_twocol_row_content.blade**

```
@extends('_twoCol_row_base')

@section('field')
  {{ $field }}
@overwrite

@section('value')
   @foreach ($value as $instance)
      <p>{{ $instance->$interface }}</p>
   @endforeach
@overwrite
```

This works when the $interface has a direct relationship and can be passed as a string (e.g. 'title'), but fails with a "call to undefined function error" when a function is passed, because the function is only defined AFTER the foreach loop has started.  I've tried everything I can think of and have search around the internet, but haven't found a way to make it work.  If I put the whole for each loop directly in the view the content renders correctly, but I loose the benefit of all the formatting that is part of the included file.

I've tried:

- Encapsulating as a string (e.g. 'blockDisplay()'), which renders the view, but not the foreach loop content.
- Wrapping in an isset, which has worked in other areas but fails because functions can't be evaluated with them
- Passing the function name as a string and then joining it to the parentheses defining it as a function in the included file (same as a string function above)
  *Edit*
- Changing _twocol_row_content.blade to look only for

  {{ $interface }}

  and passing the $instance variable as $instance->blockDisplay() fails because instance is not defined.  Wrapping $instance in an isset renders the page but not the content.

How can I render any custom functions without loosing the benefit of defining the wrapping html in a single file?

Comment: Change `{{ $interface }}` instead of `{{ $instance->$interface }}`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Sobir, I tried that, but then need to pass $interface = $instance->blockDisplay(), which fails, even with an isset.  I added the result of the experiment to my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can try this

to call object/collection value using this : `$variable->{$field}`

or object/collection that have method : `$variable->{method}()`

Comment: Ah! the braces were key! $variable-{method}() got me the result I was looking for!  Thank you!

Comment: Im also trying to do something similar, my ''Tweet'' model has a relationship with an ''Images'' table, so I have a method to call if a tweet has images, i been able to show those images however not on the users profile, seems that I need to add that method in my include. This is how Im trying to implement: ```'tweet->images' => $tweet->{images}()``` I get this: ```Use of undefined constant images - assumed 'images'```

Comment: @eduardo variable inside braces should be string

Comment: Thanks for replying back @AlzafanChristian, managed to fix this issue by using the ```asset``` helper on my foreach loop in the image tag source field. So both views (profile and home) images are displayed, didn't had to pass the method. The problem was that I could see images in one view, but not both. :-)